# PHP: Show table of results from database

Tags: php, sql

I have this simple bit of PHP that should be showing a table of invites:

```
    // connect to the database

    $host = '###';
    $username = '###';
    $pass = '###';

    mysql_connect($host,$username,$pass);
    mysql_select_db("###");

    // select everything from the news table

    $query = "SELECT * FROM creathive_applications";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr>";

    while( ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)))
    {
        echo "<td>".$row['firstname']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['lastname']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['email']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['url']."</td>";
    }

    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</table>";

    // disconnect from the database

    mysql_close();
```

However it's not working? Any ideas why and how to find out. THANKS :)

**Just to confirm, the `<table>` and `<tr>` are being outputted and the table name is `creathive_applications` with a H**

Comment: Are you getting any output at all? Does any of the HTML appear?

Comment: creathive_applications => creative_applications? (Without the h?)

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? any errors? also use only a single parentheses: `while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))`

Comment: Output $result. What does it say?

Comment: The page is here: http://creathive.net/invites/index.php there are no errors and the html is being outputted. and the table does have an h in it.

Comment: No <td>s at all. So, $result might be empty. print_r($result);

Answer (score 4):

Did your query work? You're not checking if `$result` is false after the query call. The table name sort of appears to have typo in it, possibly it should be "creative_applications" (no `h`)?

Answer (score 4):

**Okay just realised that the damn table was empty! :(
Sorry for wasting people's time!**

Comment: No wasting at all. Always fun to have my mind boggled. :P Nobody asks 'does the table contains items?' So, accept this as your own answer. ;)

Comment: LOL - Cameron, you're awesome! I make this kind of mistake, too. *probably too much*

Answer (score 2):

You should try something less dependant of your database structure :

For example :

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
echo '</pre>';
```

and check if the result is null, or return a completely different set of rows

Comment: +1 for correct coding vision. even before looking at the table. you can check what you have in result set variable which will make you a great time saving. & also avoid these type of problems.

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is its not showing up as expected in a 1 row per record layout.

That's because you have your `<TR></TR>` tags outside your loop through the records.

That section of code should look like the following

```
while( ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$row['firstname']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['lastname']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['email']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['url']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<table>
                <?php
    $host = '###';
    $username = '###';
    $pass = '###';
    $con = mysql_connect($host,$username,$pass);
    $db = '###';
    mysql_select_db($db,$con);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM creathive_applications";            
    $querycon = mysql_query($query,$con);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($querycon)){
        echo "<tr>"
        echo "<td>".$row[0]."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row[1]."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row[2]."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row[3]."</td>";
        echo "</tr>"
    }
    ?>
</table>
```

use this this will work